# How to select rows from one data.table to apply in another data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

I have two data.tables `df` (21 MIO rows) and `tmp` (500k rows)

`df` has three columns linking an original patent (`origpat`) with a reference patent (`refpat`), and tying an original classification (`mainprim`) to the `origpat`.

Below the 30 first lines are shown. Every `origpat`, `refpat` ***pair*** is unique but every `origpat` appears between 1 and 300 times and every `refpat` between 1 and 3,100 times

```
dput(df[1:30,-3])
structure(list(origpat = c(4247592, 4247592, 4247592, 4247592, 
4247592, 4247592, 4247592, 4247592, 4247592, 4247592, 4247592, 
4247592, 4247592, 4247592, 4247592, 4247592, 4247592, 4247592, 
4247592, 4247592, 4247592, 4247592, 4247592, 4247592, 4247592, 
4247592, 4247592, 4247592, 4247592, 4247592), ref.pat = c(4318978, 
4436368, 4358181, 4478622, 4312654, 4293439, 4286061, 4363648, 
4406517, 4478623, 4277285, 4375743, 4470520, 4328022, 4248614, 
4297139, 4296607, 4296608, 4395271, 4321141, 4294190, 4431420, 
4322467, 4285730, 4393138, 4246034, 4251278, 4339174, 4277322, 
4290586), mainprim = c("442", "442", "442", "442", "442", "442", 
"442", "442", "442", "442", "442", "442", "442", "442", "442", 
"442", "442", "442", "442", "442", "442", "442", "442", "442", 
"442", "442", "442", "442", "442", "442")), .Names = c("origpat", 
"ref.pat", "mainprim"), row.names = c(NA, 30L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))
```

`tmp` contains a list of patents `pnum` with their respective primary classifications `prim`. All the `origpat` and `refpat` in `df` are `pnum` (patent numbers) in `tmp`. 
As example data I give the selection of `tmp` data.table that contain all the info relating to the selected `df` variables through `dput`

```
dput(tmp)
structure(list(pnum = c("4318978", "4318978", "4318978", "4318978", 
"4318978", "4318978", "4318978", "4318978", "4436368", "4436368", 
"4436368", "4436368", "4358181", "4358181", "4358181", "4358181", 
"4478622", "4312654", "4312654", "4312654", "4312654", "4312654", 
"4312654", "4293439", "4293439", "4293439", "4293439", "4293439", 
"4293439", "4293439", "4293439", "4293439", "4293439", "4293439", 
"4293439", "4293439", "4286061", "4286061", "4286061", "4286061", 
"4286061", "4286061", "4286061", "4286061", "4363648", "4363648", 
"4363648", "4406517", "4478623", "4478623", "4277285", "4375743", 
"4375743", "4375743", "4375743", "4470520", "4470520", "4470520", 
"4328022", "4328022", "4248614", "4248614", "4248614", "4248614", 
"4248614", "4248614", "4297139", "4297139", "4297139", "4297139", 
"4297139", "4296607", "4296607", "4296607", "4296607", "4296607", 
"4296607", "4296608", "4296608", "4296608", "4296608", "4296608", 
"4395271", "4395271", "4395271", "4321141", "4321141", "4321141", 
"4321141", "4294190", "4294190", "4294190", "4294190", "4294190", 
"4294190", "4431420", "4431420", "4431420", "4431420", "4431420", 
"4431420", "4322467", "4322467", "4322467", "4322467", "4322467", 
"4322467", "4322467", "4322467", "4322467", "4322467", "4285730", 
"4285730", "4393138", "4393138", "4393138", "4393138", "4393138", 
"4393138", "4393138", "4246034", "4246034", "4246034", "4246034", 
"4251278", "4251278", "4251278", "4339174", "4339174", "4339174", 
"4339174", "4277322", "4277322", "4290586", "4290586", "4290586", 
"4290586", "4290586", "4247592", "4247592", "4247592", "4247592", 
"4247592", "4247592", "4247592", "4247592", "4247592"), prim = c("430", 
"430", "430", "430", "430", "430", "430", "430", "340", "385", 
"385", "385", "385", "385", "65", "65", "65", "118", "427", "65", 
"65", "65", "65", "106", "106", "106", "501", "501", "501", "501", 
"501", "516", "516", "516", "516", "516", "435", "435", "435", 
"435", "435", "435", "435", "435", "156", "428", "65", "385", 
"65", "65", "501", "422", "53", "53", "53", "222", "422", "604", 
"65", "65", "385", "385", "65", "65", "65", "65", "106", "106", 
"501", "501", "501", "252", "423", "423", "501", "505", "62", 
"423", "501", "501", "505", "62", "65", "65", "65", "210", "210", 
"210", "435", "118", "118", "118", "118", "118", "118", "106", 
"433", "433", "433", "433", "501", "156", "427", "427", "428", 
"428", "428", "428", "428", "428", "428", "501", "501", "426", 
"426", "426", "435", "435", "435", "435", "428", "501", "501", 
"501", "501", "501", "65", "385", "385", "385", "65", "204", 
"204", "204", "266", "266", "432", "73", "427", "427", "428", 
"442", "442", "442", "442", "8", "8")), .Names = c("pnum", "prim"
), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -147L
), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000000100788>)
```

Now, I want to compare the `mainprim` (which is linked to the `origpat`) with the different `prim` variables linked to `refpat`.

Code below works but is prohibitively slow.

```
library(data.table)
df <- data.table(df) ; setkey(df, refpat, origpat) 
refs <- unique(df$refpat) # Capture all unique refpat in df (71,000 in entire data.table)
startrow <- 0 # Set loop    
overlap <- function(a,b) sum (a == b) / length(b)
df$compare <- NA # overlap values will be inserted here

for (h in 1:length(refs)) {
  refclass <- tmp$prim[tmp$pnum == refs[h]] #subgroup of relevant 'prim'
    x <- length(df$refpat[df$refpat == refs[h]])
    prims <- df$mainprim[startrow:(startrow + x)] # isolate subset from large `df` data.table to reduce memory needed in second loop
      for (i in 1:x) {
      df$compare[startrow + i] <- overlap(prims[i], refclass) 
        }
    startrow <- startrow + x
    print(h)
  }
```

The reason I use two `for` loops is to save computer memory. I could use a single one and redetermine `refclass` for every row but that made my computer crash within minutes. This loop works but at a speed of being done in about 250 hours. 
I'm sure there are ways to simply subset the needed rows from `tmp` within `df` and then repeat this for every `origpat` but my data.table skills are not up to the task and I don't find an answer that ***explains*** how to make this work on SO or on the data.table pdf files.

Any suggestions are very welcome

EDIt @Frank The specific comparison I want to make is always changing. The main issue is the following. Consider a long `df` with two columns of linked `pnum` (patent numbers), one called `origpat` and the second called `ref.pat`. Every column contains multiple repeated `pnum` but every combination (on a single row) is unique. It establishes a link between a firm patent and an older patent. This dataset is about 22 MIO rows. 
Then I have multiple other datatables, e.g. one linking the `pnum` to the `inventors`, one linking the `pnum` to various technology classifications. What I am interested in is finding the fastest way to compare the linked data (e.g. inventors, technology classes) on a pairwise basis, with the pair defined in the rows of the `df` (i.e. `origpat` and `ref.pat`). So far the data.table solution I have is the fastest but it still takes multiple days to complete a single new comparison. 
Hope this helps

Comment: Even if your question give input data, your code does not give something very usable to understand the comaprison you're trying to achieve here. Your overlap function sounds strange too, dividing a boolean by an integer... I don't see the goal at all...

Comment: And it's hard to test, as I far as I can see (if I understood properly) there's no case where mainprim is in prim when pnum = ref.pat ...

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your comments. FYI,  `a %chin b%` gives, if I understand correctly, a vector of `TRUE` and `FALSE` that when summed give an integer (number of times `mainprim` is in `prim`). It's possible that in the example there is no single case in which `mainprim` occurs in `prim`. I should have checked that...

Comment: As far as I can tell, you're passing a single prim, doing A %in% B if A is len 1 will return a single integer

Comment: Damn Tensibai, you are right. That is not what I thought `%chin%` did. I edited the text...

Comment: Reverse the order if you wish a vector, out l'en will be lhs len

Comment: Not sure what "out l'en will be lhs len" means. By changing the code to `overlap <- function(a,b) sum (a == b) / length(b)` the problem you pointed out should be solved I think.

Comment: Do 1 %in% c(1,2,3,4) and c(1,2,3,4) %in% 1 to see what I mean ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103084/discussion-between-sjds-and-tensibai).

Comment: If you can describe the comparison you want to make, please add this to your question, in words. It can be gleaned from the answers somewhat, but really belongs in the question.

Comment: I don't understand this example - running either the given code or the answers I get a column of all zeros. It looks like the answer is doing two simple merges, but hard to tell without a meaningful example.

Comment: @eddi, I think the example indeed results in all zeros. I just extracted a part if the dataset and it's possible that the comparison is all zeros.

Comment: If you want a better answer I suggest adding a better example.

Comment: @Eddi, I agree. Will try to do that some time but right now gotta rush off to a conference. I just edited the question with a comment on my generalized question. Perhaps that clarifies things somewhat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best idea I came with is:

```
df[,idx := .I] # Add an index to the data.table to group by row of df
df[,compare := sum(tmp[pnum == ref.pat, prim] == mainprim) /
     length(tmp[pnum == ref.pat,prim]),by = idx]
```

Or reusing your `overlap` function (still using the idx column):

```
df[,compare := overlap(
                mainprim,
                tmp[pnum == ref.pat, prim]),
    by=idx]
```

What it does here is grouping by row and then use columns from Subset Data to get the `mainprim` for this row and the subsets of `tmp` needed.

If you want to avoid creating the `idx` column you can use `by=1:nrow(df)` instead but this could slow down the process (using an actual column is quicker in `data.table`).

---

Great improvements by @Docendo:

You can further speed up the process by creating an intermediate variable to store the subset instead of doing the subset twice per row:

```
df[,compare := {x = tmp[pnum == ref.pat, prim]; sum(x == mainprim) / length(x)}, by = idx]
```

And in case there are duplicated combinations of `ref.pat` and `mainprim` in `df` you could further optimize the performance by using `by = list(ref.pat, mainprim)` instead of `by = idx`:

```
df[,compare := {x = tmp[pnum == ref.pat, prim]; sum(x == mainprim) / length(x)},
   by = list(ref.pat, mainprim)]
```

And another, probably just minimal, improvement could be done by using `mean()` instead of `sum()/length()`:

```
df[,compare := mean(tmp[pnum == ref.pat, prim] == mainprim), by = list(ref.pat, mainprim)]
```

Comment: Awesome awesome awesome. My formula would have taken 10 days as I only had done about 7,500 reference patents of 73,000 since 7pm last night. Your suggestion is running now and I guess will take less then a few hours. It's 8.44 when I started it. Let's see what it gives in hour or so.

Comment: It took until 17.44, exactly 9 hours. Still a long time but much much quicker than what the for loops! Thanks again :)

Comment: Interesting! I can probably apply a similar tweak in some of my other calculations! I suppose the speed gain is from storing the initial search `tmp[pnum == ref.pat, prim]` so that it need not be done twice? Or is there something "magical" about storing stuff in temporary `x` values ?

Comment: Should note I assumed the cache would keep the subset, this working or not depends of the resulting size and memory available. Should have a dropped a word about it in the answer

Comment: Hmm this is a great idea, there tend to be many duplicates of both.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Not sure about the last idea though to replace sum / length by mean. I'm probably wrong but the ` == mainprim` limits the length of the vector no ?

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding of the problem is correct all you need is join these two tables on `ref.pat`. Make sure classes of `ref.pat` in `df` and `pnum` in `tmp` are the same. Then the desired join would be obtained by:

```
library(data.table)

df <- data.table(df)
tmp <- data.table(tmp)

setkey(df, 'ref.pat')
out <- df[tmp, nomatch = 0]
```

Comment: Hi Danas, Am I not going to create a prohibitively large new dataframe, by joining the two tables? If on average one `pnum` in `tmp` has four `prim` then `out` should result in about 84 MIO rows. It's probably true that if my computer can manage that data.table, determining the overlap would be easier but I don't think an 84 MIO row data.table will go down easily with my old computer...

Comment: Danas, I tried and as I assumed it is not possible to allocate a vector of this size. I'd also need to add `allow.cartesian = T` ...