# Simple way of showing progress in data.table "by" loops

Tags: r, data.table

I have a slow computer and some of my R calculations take hours and sometimes days to run. I'm sure they can be made more efficient but in the meanwhile I would like to find out about a simple way to show how far along R is in doing the needed calculations.

In a `loop` this can easily be done by `print(i)`. Is something similar available when doing `data.table` calculations ?

For instance, the following code takes about 50 hours to run on my machine

```
q[, ties := sum(orig[pnum == origpat, inventors] %in% ref[pnum == ref.pat, inventors]), by = idx]
```

`q` is a `data.table` with columns `origpat`, `ref.pat` and `idx` (an index) as columns. The data tables `orig` and `ref` both contain columns `pnum` and `inventors`. The code simply finds the number of overlapping inventors in both groups but given the iterative nature (`by = idx`), it takes a long time. 
I'd like my screen to post progress, e.g. for every 1,000 rows (there are about 20 mio rows).

Any way to do this simply?

Comment: Can you give a minimal reproducible example of the problem? Perhaps someone can also suggest a more efficient/faster approach to do it

Comment: Thanks for the comment, you can find an example at this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35310315/how-to-select-rows-from-one-data-table-to-apply-in-another-data-table A while ago I posted a very similar problem to this one and the solution in `data.table` is the best someone came up with.

Comment: Please edit your question, so that it's a self-contained resource and doesn't depend on other questions/links.

Comment: The code is running atm on my computer and has been for a while. I don't want to interrupt it now to create a reproducible example. If you're keen to provide a better solution to the coding problem itself, please check out the link above. This question is really about showing progress during data.table calculations.

Comment: Try `ies := {print(.GRP); sum(orig[pnum == origpat, inventors] %in% ref[pnum == ref.pat, inventors])}` This is analogous to `print(i)`

Comment: @Frank, awesome that is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks heaps !

Comment: If your computer can store 20 million rows in RAM, I'm certain it's fast enough to do whatever it is you're doing in far less than 50 hours, and you're just doing it wrong. I suggest fleshing out a proper question.

Comment: @Eddi, I posted a new question here: Note that this question was about showing progress in R. I don;t understand why you would give this minus points because that question did not require anything else but the given info. That the solution I use might not be optimal is a given but it was the best one the SO community had come up with. Hope someone will come up with something faster. That would be awesome (and I have only 4 GB ram, of which I can only use half for R so it surely isn't fast...

Comment: I didn't give this question a downvote. I did give one to your other one though.

Comment: @Frank please put your comment as answer, again :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
q[, ies := {
  print(.GRP)
  sum(orig[pnum == origpat, inventors] %in% ref[pnum == ref.pat, inventors])
}, by=idx]
```

This is analogous to `print(i)` for a by-group operation.