# Can I print something while grouping a data.table?

Tags: r, data.table, grouping

Let's say I have this data.table:

```
dt=data.table(ID=letters[seq(3,8)],category=rep(c('a','b'),each=3),value=seq(1,6))
```

I want to get the relative percentage of the value of each register relative to the sum of all values in a category. Besides that, I would like to print the category for debugging reasons. It would be something like this:

```
dt[,print(.BY[["category"]]),
    list(relative=value/sum(dt[category==.BY[["category"]],value],
    by='ID')
```

Thank you

Comment: Yes, use curly brackets, like `DT[, {print(.BY[[1]]); do_other_stuff}, by=ID]`. Example here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35552095/1191259

Comment: @Frank use *your answer* text box ;)

Comment: @jan Okay, okay :) Is it a dupe, maybe?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, you can do many steps like

```
DT[i, {
  step1
  step2
  return_value # preferably a list
}, by=g]
```

You may also check examples 2.9 ["Can I trace the `j` expression as it runs through the groups?"] and 2.8 ["What are the scoping rules for `j` expressions?"] in [the `data.table` FAQ](https://rawgit.com/wiki/Rdatatable/data.table/vignettes/datatable-faq.html).

---

In a case like the OP's example, I usually do something like:

```
r = dt[, {
  cat("\ncategory ==",.BY[[1]],"\n\n")
  out = list(ID = ID, relative = value/sum(value))
  print(setDT(out), row.names=FALSE)
  cat("\n")
  out
}, by = 'category']
```

which prints

```
category == a 

 ID  relative
  c 0.1666667
  d 0.3333333
  e 0.5000000


category == b 

 ID  relative
  f 0.2666667
  g 0.3333333
  h 0.4000000
```

If performance is an issue, you might want to tweak this somewhat, since `out` is a data.table, which is [a bad return value for `j`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Do%27s-and-Don%27ts#4-dont-coerce-j-to-list-use-list-directly). If you only need the printed result and not the object, you can replace the final `out` with `NULL`.