# Fast way to compare multiples values across dataframes in R

Tags: r, data.table, memory-efficient

This is a follow-up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35310315/how-to-select-rows-from-one-data-table-to-apply-in-another-data-table) which people found to have a bad example. It nonetheless got a reasonably good solution but it's still extremely slow.

I'm hoping for a faster way;

Reproducible example (I know it looks weird but it works)

```
set.seed(1)
class <- sample(LETTERS, 15)
origpat <- data.table(c(rep(sample(1:100),3), rep(sample(1:500), 4), sample(1:600), sample(200:299)))
set.seed(3)
refpat <- data.table(rep(seq(1,600,1),5))

dt <- data.table(rep.int(1:600,3))
dt$class <- rep(sample(LETTERS, 15),120)
dt <- dt[order(dt$V1, ascending = T)]
setnames(dt, "V1", "pnum")

df <- data.table(origpat, refpat)
colnames(df) <- c("origpat","refpat")
setkey(df, origpat)
df[, idx := .I] # you might get warning but ignore
```

So we have two data.frames: `df` contains two rows of `origpat` and `refpat` and `dt` contains a column `pnum` which captures the same numbers as `origpat` and `class` which assigns each `pnum` to three classes.

I want to find the fastest way to compare the overlap (or some other measure of comparison) between the classes found in `dt` and the two patents `origpat` and `refpat` in `df`.

This provides a working solutionL

```
df[,compare := {x = dt[pnum== origpat, class]; y = dt[pnum == refpat, class]; sum(x %in% y)}, by = idx]
```

The problem with this solution is that it seems fast but the real dataset

- Contains over 22 MIO rows
- Has over 92,000 `pnum` and over 5,000 `class` elements
- Number of `class` elements per patent differs between 1 and 26
- Not sure if this makes a difference but the `pnum`, `origpat`, and `refpat` are characters, not numbers.

For general purposes it should be possible that `x` and `y` are found in different datasets (hence not both in `dt` and the solution should be applicable to big datasets. The current solution applied to my data takes about 1 minute for 100 rows. I have 20 million rows so that takes long.

Hope this provides a sensible reproducible example that allows for finding a good solution

Comment: in `df`, you have two columns with the same name, and each row is identical (because you have ordered/setkey `origpat` & `refpat`). This seems odd

Comment: Correct this is not how it should be. Will update

Comment: Sorry, y is wrong. Will change immediately

Comment: No, the columns origpat and refpat have the same length. the sum(x == y) is meant to capture the number of overlapping elements (in this example `class`) in x and y. It might be better to use `sum(x %in% y)`  which is what I am currently running

Comment: I'll think about this, but just to clarify - this is a different question from your earlier linked one, right? In particular `df` here doesn't have the "class"/"mainprim" column.

Comment: Yeah it is different but the principle is very similar: How to fast compare info (class, inventors) stored in separate data.tables that is uniquely linked to a specific identifier (pnum)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple way of making it faster by rewriting your loops, but I still feel a little fuzzy on the question:

```
setkey(dt, pnum)
df[, compare := {x = dt[.(origpat), class];
                 dt[.(refpat), sum(x %in% class), by = .EACHI]$V1}
   , by = origpat]
```

Comment: I'm trying to make this work but it does not. Do `origpat` and `refpat` here refer to separate objects or are they the column names of `df` ?

Comment: I get this error: Error in vecseq(f__, len__, if (allow.cartesian || notjoin || !anyDuplicated(f__,  : 
  Join results in 442953 rows; more than 279302 = nrow(x)+nrow(i). Check for duplicate key values in i each of which join to the same group in x over and over again. If that's ok, try by=.EACHI to run j for each group to avoid the large allocation. If you are sure you wish to proceed, rerun with allow.cartesian=TRUE. Otherwise, please search for this error message in the FAQ, Wiki, Stack Overflow and datatable-help for advice. `allow.cartesian = T` does not change anything

Comment: After doing the `setkey(dt, pnum)` once the speed of my code went times 100. Unfortunately I pressed the wrong button and failed to save the results (it did 2 MIO rows in less than two hours). Now I can't get that speed back. NO idea wtf happened :((((

Comment: Ok I figured the latter out. Saving `ref.pat` as a numeric instead of character increases the speed dramatically

Comment: use `%chin%` for characters to improve the speed - should be pretty close to `%in%` on numerics